# Matlab: extracting rows with specific datetime

Tags: matlab, datetime, rows

I have a datetime row containing dates/times such as 15-May-2016 18:30:00. I am trying to extract only rows with hours ending in :00:00, such as 15-May-2016 18:00:00, in order to work with hourly data only. Picking only every nth row does not work because certain times skip in the data, such as:

```
StreamData.datetime:
```

...

21-Apr-2016 12:00:00

21-Apr-2016 12:15:00

21-Apr-2016 12:30:00

21-Apr-2016 12:45:00

21-Apr-2016 13:00:00

21-Apr-2016 14:45:00

21-Apr-2016 15:00:00

...

This is also why I do not want to aggregate averages on hourly data, but want only the rows with datetime ending in :00:00.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%% Your data
date = ['21-Apr-2016 12:00:00';
        '21-Apr-2016 12:15:00';
        '21-Apr-2016 12:30:00';
        '21-Apr-2016 12:45:00';
        '21-Apr-2016 13:00:00';
        '21-Apr-2016 14:45:00';
        '21-Apr-2016 15:00:00'];

data = (1:7)'; % example (data)

%% convert date to vector extracting minutes and second (via datenum first)   
[~,~,~,~,minutes,seconds] = datevec(datenum(date,'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS'));

%% Index zero minutes and zero seconds    
zero_minutes = minutes == 0;
zero_seconds = seconds == 0;

%% Get at the hour indices (rows)
at_the_hour_rows = zero_minutes & zero_seconds; 

%% Example extracting corresponding data  
at_the_hour_data = data(at_the_hour_rows);
```

Comment: The second step (zero_minutes = ) gives logical 1 and 0s if true or false, with the third step giving the same thing; therefore the final result is that at_the_hour_data is a character array of single digit numbers 0, 1, or 2

Comment: @Sara - at_the_hour_rows gives you logical (True or False) for zero_minutes and zero_seconds - you then use at_the_hour_rows to extract your data of interest. The last line (at_the_hour_data) is just an example extracting corresponding data from a vector containing 1 to 7 (the sample data I made up) and could be ignored. I hope this helps.

Comment: Then should not this work?: `at_the_hour_data = StreamData.datetime(at_the_hour_rows);` ? Because it only gives a character array

Comment: @Sara - you need to convert your date to an appropriate format, e.g., by using datenum (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html?searchHighlight=datenum) that Matlab can work with before manipulating your date data - else you could get unexpected output. I did this ([~,~,~,~,minutes,seconds] = datevec(datenum(date,'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS'));) before converting the dates to vectors. Copy the entire example and run it line by line and see how it works. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks OsJoe! I figured it out. My biggest problem was using `dataset` instead of `readtable`, and not having datetime as text. It works great now.

Comment: @Sara - great! I am glad it helped! Please accept the answer to indicate that your question has been resolved. Good luck with your work!